# Rules and VBO, data deletion without reason

Tags: rules, views

I use VBO module to batch assign taxonomy terms with Rule Component. The problem is that the taxonomy term is successfully inserted in all selected nodes BUT it also deletes the data of another field, for an unknown reason. The settings of my rule is:

```
Variables:
datatype=node,
datatype=Taxonomy term

Conditions:
Entity has field
Parameter: Entity: [node], Field: field_agora_category

Actions:
Set a data value
Parameter: Data: [node:field-agora-category], Value: [term]
```

I don't use any wrong fields in Rules configuration but it deletes the data of another field (type:Geospatial data).
Is that possible? Is it a bug?

I use:

**Drupal    7.18**

**Rules 7.x-2.2**

**Views Bulk Operations 7.x-3.1**

Comment: Is that geospatial data by any chance provided by the Geocoder module for a field that is configured to geolocate from another field?  If in such a case geolocation fails, the data that existed will be erased.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't know exactly how it is working.It's part of Cartaro distribution. Is there any way to avoid data deletion?

Comment: You have to at least be willing to check how the data is provided yourself-- or rely on a vendor for professional support.  What kind of field is the data being deleted from?

Comment: Patrick, here you can read some more about the Geospatial Data field: http://cartaro.org/documentation/store-geospatial-data

Comment: And here:http://drupal.org/node/1458496

Comment: According to the module's page, the PostGIS module is used on less than 100 sites.  That is an extremely small number for a Drupal module.  I would file a bug in the module's issue queue: http://drupal.org/project/issues/postgis?categories=All